# create dask DataFrame from a list of dask Series

Tags: dataframe, dask

I need to create a a dask DataFrame from a set of dask Series,
analogously to constructing a pandas DataFrame from lists

```
pd.DataFrame({'l1': list1, 'l2': list2})
```

I am not seeing anything in the API. The dask DataFrame constructor is not supposed to be called by users directly and takes a computation graph as it's mainargument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general I agree that it would be nice for the `dd.DataFrame` constructor to behave like the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

If your series have well defined divisions then you might try [dask.dataframe.concat](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.multi.concat) with `axis=1`.

You could also try converting one of the series into a DataFrame and then use assignment syntax:

```
L = # list of series
df = L[0].to_frame()
for s in L[1:]:
    df[s.name] = s
```